# What does it mean to have two parameters in a getattr()?

Tags: python

From the python official doc, I saw the normal expression of getattr();

getattr(object, name[, default])

I understood it quite well. For example, I can do:

```
>>> def a():
...     pass
...
>>> c = 2
>>> getattr(a, 'b', c)
2
```

But In the code I'm viewing now, the author use a pattern like:

```
getattr(a, b.x)(b.y)
```

And I even didn't find 'b' in 'a' object!

This confused me a lot, what does this code mean?

---

Appendix 1:

The getattr() is between a plenty of import statements. 
And the original expression is like:

```
 from tornado.options import define, options
 import settings      

 getattr(settings, options.env)(options.server_name)
```

Comment: He's shortcutting, the attribute is a function which he calls with the `b.y` as it's argument. Show us more code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is an object, not a literal. The author of this code is saying "get me the attribute of `a` whose name is given by whatever `b.x` is, and call it passing whatever `b.y` is".

Comment: Should I think that getattr(a, b.x) get a callable object, and he called this object with b.y parameter?

Comment: Yes. `b.y` is not an argument to getattr, but to the callable retrieved by getattr.

Answer (score 1):

The author is calling a function. The following:

```
getattr(a, b.x)(b.y)
```

gets an attribute from object `a`. The author has an object `b` which has at least two attributes, `x and y`. He gets an attribute from `a` which is name is the same as `b.x`. That is apparently a function which he calls with an argument, a value from `b.y`

Simplified example:

```
>>> class Ex(object):
...     def foo(self, val):
...         """ b.x has the string "foo", which is the name of this method """
...         print val # <-- b.y 
...         
...     
... 
>>> class B(object):
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...         
...     
... 
>>> a = Ex()
>>> b = B("foo", 1)
>>> getattr(a, b.x)(b.y)
1
```

In the example above, we're getting a method from object `a` called `foo`. Notice that `b.x` value is `"foo"`. `b.y` is `1`, which is passed to `a.foo()` as the `val`.

Comment: I understand that get b.x string in a, but is b.y the default, or b.y is the parameter pass to b.x?

Comment: If the 3rd argument is omitted, `getattr` raises an exception instead of returning a default value. `b.y` is the parameter to the function call.

Comment: @chepner, How wired is that, getattr allow string only, but when you treat it as a callable object, he'll allow you to use objects!

Comment: What's weird? `b.x` evaluates to a string, or `getattr` would raise a `TypeError`. If `b.x` is `"foo"`, for example, then `a` has an attribute `foo` which is callable. In other words, `a` may have two callable attributes `foo` and `bar`, and which one gets called is determined by the value of `b.x`.

Answer (score 0):

`b.x` is some attribute containing a string. There is nothing special, it's simply a variable instead of a constant `'b'` in your first example.
Written in more than one line:

```
name = b.x
func = getattr(a, name) # get the function by name
result = func(b.y) # call the function
```

Comment: Then what does the additional (b.y) mean?

Comment: @Zen that `y` is other attribute that is passed as function argument.

Answer (score 0):

He must doing something like this example:

```
>>> a = 10
>>> class B:
...  def __init__(self, y):
...    self.y = y
...  def x(self, y):
...   return y
... 
>>> b = B(20)
>>> getattr(a, 'b', b.x)(b.y)
20
>>>
```

Here, `b` is an object with `x` as a "function attribute" that accepts `y` argument as `b`'s objects other attribute.

`getattr(a, 'b', b.x)` returns function reference, in my example it returns `x`, so in my example `getattr(a, 'b', b.x)(b.y)` is equivalent to `b.x(b.y)`.

Check here is another example for inbuilt object list:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> getattr(a, 'b', L.append)(L[0])
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
>>>
```

Because `a` is simple int e.g. `a = 10` and `'b'` is not an attribute of `a`, so `L.append` returned by `getattr` function and L.append called with `L[0]` that is 1 is appended at list L.

I think below example will further help you:

```
>>> L.append
<built-in method append of list object at 0x7fd34e62c7a0>
>>> getattr(a, 'b', L.append)
<built-in method append of list object at 0x7fd34e62c7a0>
>>>
```